# No module named 'index' after install pyflann

Tags: python, python-3.x, flann

I have some problems installing `pyflann` in python 3.7.3, after execute:

```
pip install pyflann
```

The installation is successfully accomplished, but when I import the library and a run a python program, I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyflann\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from index import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'index'
```

I'm using window 10. **How can I fixed?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pyflann` does not have support for python 3 yet, according to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/primetang/pyflann/issues/1). Your two options are:

Install the [`pyflann-py3`](https://pypi.org/project/pyflann-py3/) package:

```
pip install pyflann-py3
```

Or, you could take the advice from the issue and use [2to3](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/2to3.html):

```
sudo 2to3 -w D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyflann
```

Comment: Note that the github repo for pyflann-py3 is gone, so it's clearly not maintained anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The pyflann package is not compatible with Python 3. It looks like
it is not actively maintained, the last commit was in February 2017:

https://github.com/primetang/pyflann/commits/master

There is an open issues documenting the problem:

https://github.com/primetang/pyflann/issues/1

There are a few open PRs trying to add Python 3 support that were never
merged:

https://github.com/primetang/pyflann/pulls

You might have better luck with one of the forks, but I can't vouch for them,
I've never used pyflann:

https://github.com/primetang/pyflann/network/members